# How to inject custom service in SAPUI5

Tags: dependency-injection, sapui5

Is there a concept in SAPUI5 similar to angular services? I need to inject a custom service (basically a class with some methods) to another custom class, and I was expecting that the framework would automatically instantiate my custom service, but when I try to use it it's a constructor and not the object.
The code, pruned by not necessary details, is here:

The custom service:

```
    sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/Object",
    "ArA/model/productionOrdersDefinition/Order"
], function(Object, Order) {
    "use strict";
    return Object.extend("ArA.model.productionOrdersDefinition.InputProvider", {
        constructor: function() {

        },
        onInit: function(){
            this.order = new Order();
            this.order.id  = "0000133535";
            // ...
        },
        getOrder: function(){
            // ...
            return this.order;
        }
    });
});
```

The object using the custom service:

```
    sap.ui.define([
    "ArA/model/productionOrdersDefinition/BaseObject",
    "ArA/model/productionOrdersDefinition/Order",
    "ArA/model/productionOrdersDefinition/InputProvider"
], function(BaseObject, Order, InputProvider) {
    "use strict";
    return BaseObject.extend("ArA.model.productionOrdersDefinition.ManagerProgrammazione", {
        constructor: function() {
            BaseObject.call(this);
            // this  InputProvider is a constructor (method) and getOrder is not a function
            var order = InputProvider.getOrder();
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that you try to transfer you experience and concepts from Angular to UI5. But it's better to do it in a way that was designed in UI5 world :)

There is a concept of models, which are aimed to basically deal with data. You can create your own model just as you did - an extension of base UI5 object or  [JSONModel](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel). Most probably you are not going to use OData protocol for network communication so you will store you data in JSONModel.

Declare domain-specific methods in your model(s) and instantiate them in your controllers directly or in the application's component (if you want to have a kind of global model available for all controllers). You can get the instance of component from any controller via [getOwnerComponent](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller/methods/getOwnerComponent) method.

Another approach to organize your data models - is to create a special kind of object called "BO" - Business Object, this BO will handle all domain-specific affairs (instantiate needed models, do the networking, data manipulation and so on). So you would need to create this BO in your controller and call needed high-level methods on it from controller once user-actions are triggered.

In addition, you will have to take care of destruction of your models/BOs in controller or component lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just add instantiation to the code, and it should start working:

```
var this._oInputProvider = new InputProvider();
var order = this._oInputProvider.getOrder();
```

Comment: Yes, I did this and it works. I came from C# and usually I avoid to instantiate a dependency in the class using it in order to make it "unit testable", but effectiverly in js I can inject a different constructor